# Flex Mobile iOS adhoc displays black screen after launch

Tags: ios, apache-flex, flash-builder

my Flex iOS application displays black screen after splash screen.nothing happens and couldn't see any proper errors on debug utility.

I can build adhoc using flash builder and it's works fine but problem occurs when I create ipa using dumped config file on command line(ant)

I'm using flex sdk 4.6 and AirSDK 15.0(overladed) .my application includes few native extensions.

```
mxmlc

mxmlc -load-config app-config.xml src/mobapp.mxml -output myapp.swf



adt

<target name="build-release-adhoc-package-ipa">

    <echo>::building captive-runtime release-adhoc ipa..</echo>

    <exec executable="${FLEX_BIN}/adt" failonerror="true">

        <arg line="-package" />

        <arg line="-target ipa-ad-hoc" />

        <arg line="-storetype pkcs12" />

        <arg line="-keystore ${provision.dir}/release-adhoc.p12" />

        <arg line="-storepass 12345" />

        <arg line="-provisioning-profile ${provision.dir}/release_adhoc.mobileprovision" />

        <arg line="${adhoc.dir}/ios-adhoc.ipa" />

        <arg line="${src}/mobapp-app.xml" />

        <arg line="myapp.swf" />

        <arg line="${icon.dir}/applicationIcon16.png" />

        <arg line="${icon.dir}/applicationIcon32.png" />

        <arg line="${icon.dir}/applicationIcon36.png" />

        <arg line="${icon.dir}/applicationIcon48.png" />

        <arg line="${icon.dir}/applicationIcon57.png" />

        <arg line="${icon.dir}/applicationIcon72.png" />

        <arg line="${icon.dir}/applicationIcon76.png" />

        <arg line="${icon.dir}/applicationIcon114.png" />

        <arg line="${icon.dir}/applicationIcon120.png" />

        <arg line="${icon.dir}/applicationIcon128.png" />

        <arg line="${icon.dir}/applicationIcon152.png" />

        <arg line="${base.dir}/Default-568h@2x.png" />

        <arg line="-extdir ${src}/ane" />

        <arg line="-platformsdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPh oneOS.sdk" />

    </exec>

    </target>
```

please help.

Comment: Compile your swf in debug mode and add the debugging connect command to your adt invocation.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for the comment.I'll try.and I want to know why it's stuck on splash screen when build ipa on command line.and the connect command only works with ipa-debug.is there any option should I add for adhoc?

Comment: It's in the ADT documentation.